# Passing variable into onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, variables

I'm pretty new to Android, so sorry if my problem seems basic.  I spent all last night looking it up and couldn't find a solution (which makes me think I may have a fundamental flaw in what I'm trying to achieve).

Basically, I'm trying to call a method from inside onOptionsItemSelected.  In the Android Developer documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) they give this example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

However, in my application, I have methods called by onOptionsItemSelected that require an input.  In the context of the example I'm using from the Android Developer website this would equate to me wanting to pass the integer "myint" to the newGame method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item, int myint) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame(myint);
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

When I do this, Eclipse comes up with an error for the row "public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {" saying that I need to remove the "@Override" command.

I've not been able to find any examples on the internet where people are passing variables through onOptionsItemSelected (or methods like onConfigurationChanged) in this way, which is why I think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding in how this works.  Unfortunately, I'm not really sure where to start with tackling this correctly.  At the moment I'm using "public static" variables, so my methods (newGame in this example) can access them, but I realise the use of these type of variables seem to be generally frowned upon.

If anyone could help me with this or even point me in the direction of what I would need to search/read I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: so this is code for your menu? Are you making a game?

Comment: This was just an example I took from the Android Developer website.  My actual application is a vocab testing app.  It seemed easier to use the clutter-free code from Google that I knew would be error-free!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a private non-static variable in your class, and when you select the menu item, you can just read:

```
case R.id.new_game:
    newGame(this.myint);
    return true;
```

And have at the top of your class:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private int myint;
```

You'll just have to make sure you have a value assigned to it before the user is clicking on the menu item!

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you.  It's also looks a lot easier to implement than I was expecting!